# Swift Selectors with UILocalizedIndexedCollation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

For the past few months, I've been using a UILocalizedIndexedCollation to sort a UITableView by a core data property "lastName" on a User NSObject.
My current code to determine the section for each user looks like this:

```
addUserObject.section = self.collation.sectionForObject(user, collationStringSelector: Selector("lastName"))
```

However, in Xcode 7.3, I get a compiler warning:

```
No method declared with Objective-C selector 'lastName'
```

My first thought was to use the new Selector formatting, like so:

```
Selector(User.lastName)
```

But this generates an error:

```
Instance member 'lastName' cannot be used on type 'User'
```

The code works fine as-is, but I'd like to get rid of the warning in the 'correct' way. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The new syntax in Swift 2.2 for selectors is #selector(your_method_name).

In your case the compiler warns you that you do not have a method called "lastName". From the looks of it you are trying to pass an object property as a selector which has to be a method.

The second error tells you that you are trying to access a **class** property but the **class** does not have such a property. You probably want to access an **instance** variable.